Why do we care about the binormal vector and osculating plane?
In Calculus 3 we learn about vector functions, and one of the first things we learn about them is how they can create space curves/paths. The first applications we learn about has to do with physics, and imagining that a vector function $\vec{r}(t)$ could draw a curve that represents the position of a particle at any time. From there we cover $\vec{r'}(t)$ (velocity), $\vec{r''}(t)$ (acceleration), $\vec{T}(t)$ (unit tangent vector, our direction of travel), $\vec{N}(t)$ (the direction we turn), and finally $\vec{B}(t)$ (the binormal vector).
From there we also learn that the binormal vector can be used to define the osculating plane, but that's really the only application I've heard about for it. Regarding the osculating plane, I've read things online that say it is our "best approximation of the curve $\vec{r}(t)$ at that given point", but while I understand that the plane matches the curve's path (visually), I don't really know what it means to "approximate the curve". I would think that would be given by a tangent line to the curve at a given point, not an entire plane. And a tangent line as a linear approximation is a very useful thing because it can simplify really nasty functions and allow us to approximate the solution much more easily (provided we're "close" to the center point). This naturally translates for tangent planes of surfaces and more as we delve further into math. But I'm not sure how the osculating plane really does any of those things.
I also read that there's a physics application of something called the osculating circle but again I'm not seeing how this relates to much of the other math we do in various math courses.
Could someone give an approachable reason as to why we care about the binormal vector and osculating plane, and perhaps what they tell us (in the context of an object moving through space)? (from the viewpoint of someone who has only taken lower-division, undergrad math classes)
Thank you!

"Best approximation" can be understood in the sense of the Taylor expansion of the curve near a point. You could start from the wikipedia page about Frenet-Serret formulas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas  See the paragraph about the Taylor expansion and also the applications.

Briefly, one wants an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$ at each point that is registering the geometry of the curve. You might find Section 2 of Chapter 1 of my differential geometry text (freely available at the link in my profile) helpful.

@Gribouillis I still don't quite get it. The Taylor Series is just an extension of the tangent line idea, where (provided convergence holds) we can construct an infinitely long polynomial that perfectly approximates some function. I would think that would translate in 3D to having a tangent line/path at a point on a space curve and then making a quadratic-looking path/curve, etc...but since a curve is a curve and a plane is a plane, I don't see how a plane could approximate a curve.

@TedShifrin it seems that for someone in an entry-level multivariable Calculus course then (who hasn't taken linear algebra or differential geometry) then this is just a topic that gets introduced "because we can" but the reason won't be studied for a while (if at all, for non-math majors?). Is that accurate?

Yes, although the words “orthonormal basis” do not require linear algebra. You’ll be amused (?) to know that, despite being a differential geometer, I never included this material when I taught multivariable calculus 25+ times in my career. Curvature is a reasonable topic — including the discussion of acceleration and how to bank roads safely.

This is slightly related to Torsion intuition, but not as directly as I'd like. I think this question has a good answer expanding on Wikipedia's "Thus in a sense the osculating plane is the closest plane to the curve at a given point.", but I am not in a position to write it now.

@TedShifrin I appreciate the directness. I too don't really enjoy teaching things--especially in a gen. ed. course--unless it's going to come up in an immediate course (or at worse one after the one they're taking). It's nice to hear the realness of "this isn't really relevant in this class."

Yes, the osculating plane at $\vec r(0)$ is the unique plane with the property that the distance from the curve to the plane is $O(s^3)$ for $s\approx 0$. It is the limit of the planes spanned by three distinct points on the curve, $\vec r(0), \vec r(h), \vec r(k)$, as $h,k\to 0$.
